# Not able to download multiple files using XMLHttpRequest and Xhtml2pdf

Tags: javascript, python, django

Hi I am trying to generate and download multiple files using XXLHttpRequest but it's never getting into response of javascript's request.

Here is my javascript code:

```
{%block javascript%}
<script type="text/javascript">

function exportPDFForAll(employees) {
var employeesList = [
{% for emp in employees %}
    {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %}
    {
        name: "{{ emp.name }}"

    }
{% endfor %}
]


alert(employeesList)

for (var i = 0; i < employeesList.length; i++){
    var params = 'selectedName='+employeesList[i].name+'&selectedDate='+$('#date').val()+'&csrfmiddlewaretoken='+$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "/exportallsheets/", true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = req.response;
        console.log(blob.size);
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download=employeesList[i].name+"_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
        link.click();
    };

    req.send(params);
  }
}
</script>
{%endblock%}
```

and here is my render class in Django:

```
from io import BytesIO, StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa


class Render:

@staticmethod
def render(path: str, params: dict):
    template = get_template(path)
    html = template.render(params)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        # return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %(params['name'])
        content = "inline; filename=%s" %(filename)

        content = "attachment; filename=%s" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        print(response)
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error Rendering PDF", status=400)
```

The code works fine from javascript to Django and it creates pdfs as well in memory but it never gets back to req.onload callback. But if I try for single file and don't use javascript/ajax etc then it works fine and directly downloads the file. I am so confused, any help would be highly appreciated. I am running on a deadline :(

Comment: Is it throwing any errors? Try console logging the req.readyState to see if it's sending at all. Also logging in an .onerror event might help too.

Comment: I tried but I could find any errors. I debugged the whole code it works but it just never comes back to onload callback.

Comment: Hmm that's not good. Possibly onload being unset somewhere if you're certain everything else is working. Try adding `req.onreadystatechange = ()=>{console.log(req.readyState);};` and see what it logs out.

Comment: Ok ill try this out and let you know

Comment: I solved it by making some changes. I removed ajax part and in a loop I created pdfs and added them into a zip and simply downloaded them. But thanks for your timely response. I appreciate it.